# How do you find a quadratic approximation to the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: approximation, fibonacci-numbers

I found this question in a website somewhere, tried solving it, failed. So I'm asking here:
How do you find a quadratic approximation to the Fibonacci sequence? By approximation I mean a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$ such that for all integer values of $x < n$, $ax^2 + bx + c  = f(x)$, where $n$ is maximized, and $f(n)$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: There is no such quadratic approximation. Note the Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially fast, so at most, you can interpolate between 3 points. If you want a polynomial that matches for more points, look up interpolation methods.

Comment: oh k. That's pretty nice to know . Do yo have any source for that number? I'd really like to understand why.

Comment: Number? 3? Its just like linear approximations. Given 3 points, you can't force a straight line to go through all 3 points, but you can make a quadratic do this. Likewise, an $n$th degree polynomial can interpolate through $n+1$ points.

Comment: ah. Gosh, now I feel like an idiot :-}. Thanks for pointing it out, and thanks for the help.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is based on a recurrence relation (difference equation) i.e. $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$. The analysis of such recurrences shows that, apart from exceptional cases, the asymptotic behaviour is governed by the greatest root of an auxiliary polynomial (in the case of Fibonacci $x^2-x-1=0$) and if that root is $\alpha$ the sequence approaches $A\alpha^n$ - and this is incompatible with general quadratic approximation.

Comment: What do you mean by "governed by the greatest root of an auxiliary" polynomial?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing quite like that, however 
$$ x^2 + xy - y^2 = \pm 1 $$ where $x<y$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers.
$$3^2 + 3 \cdot 5 - 5^2 = -1,$$ $$5^2 + 5 \cdot 8 - 8^2 = 1.  $$

Answer (score 1):

To explain "governed by the largest root of an auxiliary polynomial" ... (should be largest in absolute value)

Suppose $u_{n+1}=(\alpha+\beta)u_n-\alpha\beta u_{n-1}$

(and for higher degree recurrences we take corresponding numbers of roots and the relevant symmetric polynomials - for the Fibonacci numbers $\alpha+\beta=1, \alpha\beta=-1$)

Then it is easy to check that $u_n=A\alpha^n +B\beta^n$ is a solution and if $u_0=V, u_1=W$ we have $$V=A+B, W=A\alpha +B\beta$$ So that $W-\beta V=A(\alpha-\beta)$ and $W-\alpha V=B(\beta-\alpha)$ give $A$ and $B$. If we have $|\alpha|\gt |\beta|, A \neq 0$ (so roots are not equal, the coefficient of the largest root is non-zero) then the asymptotic behaviour follows $A\alpha^n$.

Now I expressed the recurrence in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but generally it will be  $u_{n+1}=Pu_n-Q u_{n-1}$ and we recover $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as roots of the auxiliary quadratic $x^2-Px+Q=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For short, there isn't any non-zero polynomial such that $p(x+2)=p(x+1)+p(x)$.
If we assume that the leading coefficient of the LHS is $L\neq 0$, the leading coefficient of the RHS is $2L\neq L$, hence polynomial approximations of the whole Fibonacci sequence are out of question. But clearly one may use Lagrange interpolation to get just a few terms, and
$$ F_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n $$
is well-known and easy to prove.